# phpstorm create new php file looks different than other phpfiles no hinting

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am very new to phpstorm but would like to start using it.

I imported a directory into a new project.

When I right click in the directory and select new>php file and give it a new the file is created.

In the file however I don't see the code hinting/colors I see on my other phpfiles.

the icon for the file is also the regular "file" icon which is not the purple phpfile icon.

The file extension is .php though.

what am I missing?

edit: I originally created the file by clicking new>file

And it was not a phpfile. Then I deleted it and recreated it with the same name but as a php file.

So If I "refactor" the file with a new name it seems to be ok. But what if I want to keep it the same name?

Comment: http://imgur.com/gFpdg9p - do you click on this one?

Comment: @michael Yes but originally I had clicked just blank file one. Then deleted it. Then I clicked the phpfile and gave it the same name. And now it seems to be stuck as that?

Comment: I've experienced this a couple of times, too. Actually, sometimes it works after I deleted the file on the server and redownloaded it, or try to delete it locally, close the project, close phpstorm and create it after reopening.. But I guess this is a general bug... Though phpstorm is great!

Comment: I've had many problems with phpstorm and it's formatting recently. One day it tells me I made a misteke somewhere and the next day the exact same file is ok. On another occation I reformatted my code and it completely messed up and some minutes and a reload later I could fix it with another reformat. So phpstrom definately has some problems here. So don't be too confused if you can't find the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping. Really new to it so it seemed like I did something wrong. Which I guess in a way I did.

Comment: Do not see any bugs here... In any case: did you managed to get it working or not?

Comment: Well I just created a new PHP file with a different name and it worked. but I can't make a php file with the same name as the one I created and then deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Settings | File Types`
- `Text files` entry
- Find and remove offending pattern

Comment: Ah thank you. So I guess by saving a file without an extension it gets added as a file type in phpstorm?

Comment: No. When opening such file IDE is asking you how to treat it, text file is preselected by default. Most likely you just clicked "OK" (or whatever the button was) without paying attention to the dialog.